# How to fix Wandb API giving error 400 when deleting artifacts?

Tags: wandb

I accidentally logged way too much to wandb and would like to delete some artifacts. I've tried the following script, but I get an error 400 whenever I run it:

```py
import wandb

wandb.login(key=KEY)

api = wandb.Api(overrides={"project": PROJECT, "entity": ENTITY})

for run in api.runs():
    files = sorted([f for f in run.logged_artifacts()], key=lambda f: f.updated_at)
    print("Total files:", len(files))
    print("Last file:", files[-1].name)
    print("Last file date:", files[-1].updated_at)
    for f in files[:-1]:
        if ".tar" in f.name:
            # also tried just f.delete()
            a = api.artifact(f"{PROJECT}/{f.name}")
            print("Deleting {}".format(f.name))
            a.delete()
```

All I get is `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.wandb.ai/graphql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work at Weights & Biases, I checked internally and it might be related to the artifacts having aliases, you might just need to try:

```
a.delete(delete_aliases=True)
```